# Reduce MongoDB memory usage

Tags: mongodb

I have deployed a Mongo Community server docker in WSL Ubuntu and currently running MongoDB aggregate Query and downloading some data from Mongo. I set up the Mongo memory limit to 32 GB. However, after my query ran Mongo occupied around 22.4 GB.
[image]

To fix this I added Mongo tcmallocReleaseRate as 9.0 in `/etc/mongod.conf` file.

```yaml
setParameter:
  tcmallocReleaseRate: 9.0
```

However, still, my memory usage is very high
[image]

This is adding a heavy load on our servers despite my mongo operation being finished. I am wondering how can I tell Mongo to free up this memory to system.

Comment: Did you configure the cache size in mongod.conf?

Comment: @joe no do I need to? I was wondering it would use the memory when it needs to but free up later shouldn't this be the case?

Comment: The mongod will hold on to 80% of the cache persistently, if left to its own defaults, it will set it cache size to about 50% of the amount of memory that the OS reports is there.

Comment: Fred differently: what's the underlying problem that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @user20042973 basically when we do DB-intensive operations it crashes our whole DB, due to memory usage. Trying to resolve it